# PDO beginTransaction on diferrent classes

Tags: php, class, pdo

you may excuse me, but as far as i can understand, PDO beginTransaction is used for testing all required queries and if all return success, they are all executed..am i right?
if yes, i want to ask you if i can use that on multiple queries but by different classes..

i have a class Notifications and a class Followers, on the same page.

```
class Notifications{

    private $pdo;
    public $now;

public function __construct(){
    $now=time();
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $this->pdo = $db->getConnection();
}

////////////INSERT NOTIFICATIONS/////////////////////
    public function InsertNoti($toid, $title, $description, $link){
    $sql = "blah blah";
    $result = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute(array(':toid'=>$toid));
    }
}
```

and Follow about the same..what i want is beginTransaction->execute Follow if success -> Insert Notification..Is it possible using the beginTransaction or do i have to use if(successNotification){then execute follow}?

Comment: Did you try to read documentation about transactions? Or explore some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. PDO::beginTransaction() starts a transaction. Each SQL statement inside the transaction is normally *executed*, not tested. If none of them fail, all are either committed or rolled back at the same time. Both committing and rolling back can result in errors, which you need to trap and handle.

After you begin a transaction, the PDO object will wait for you to issue a PDO::commit() or PDO::rollback(). It doesn't really matter what you do between beginning and ending a transaction, although you want to keep transactions open for as short a time as possible. You just need to be careful not to do anything that causes an implicit commit. In MySQL, for example, any DDL within a transaction will commit the transaction.

It's not crystal clear what you're trying to do, but one of these seems likely. (Pseudocode, error handling omitted for simplicity.)

```
begin transaction
insert notification
commit
if no errors, then
begin transaction
insert follow
commit
```

or

```
begin transaction
insert notification
insert follow
commit
```

You should read the [PDO docs about transactions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php) carefully.

Comment: can i get the lastInsertId() from the first query..? i need to insert it to the second... Like, insert Notification, Get the id from the notification, exec the "follow" query

Comment: If only there were *some* way to search for documentation. [PDO::lastInsertID](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)